# spaces between two math symbols

Tags: spacing

I know that we can type`\quad` or`\,` to make extra space between two symbol, but are there some methods to achieve this purpose without typing these commands everytime?

Comment: Please provide more context.  Are there particular symbol combinations whose spacing you find deficient?  And even if it is more than just an isolated case, you could clarify, for example, space around relational symbols, space between variables, etc.

Comment: Are there some methods to make this spacing without typing these commands everytime?

Comment: Why do you need this space between all symbols?

Comment: it is impossible to answer your question in this generality, what do you mean by "symbol" here, do you want `$ab$` to be typeset as _a b_ instead of  _ab_  (that is relatively hard as it is specified in the font) or do you want `$a+b` typeset as _a_  `  +  `  _b_ rather than _a_ `+` _b_ (that is relatively easy as tex has a parameter to control space around binary operators)

Comment: TeX classifies math-mode symbols as being of type "ordinary", "binary", "relational", "operator", "math-open", "math-close", etc. Depending on the symbol types and their combination, TeX may insert a bit of whitespace before and/or after each symbol. Unless you tell us which symbols you have in mind, it's going to be well-nigh impossible to provide specific advice on what you should do.